# Label X of Y counting formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am struggling from some time now to create a formula in excel and also in gsheets... for a major problem:

- we have orders from a online marketplace
- in one order define by ORDER ID... we can have maybe one product... sometimes multiple products...
  ...this is how export orders look like:

[image: export img]

i need to create count for printing labels for each order... based on qty and also number of products... 1 of 5, 2 of 5, 3 of 5... so on... to verify all the products for entire order (same ID)...

those count labels are based on total qty and total no of products.... in one order...

is a similar thing for AWB delivery/expedition for courier.... multiple destination, multiple/different numbers of boxes for each destinations...

can u help us with a formula or a way to create those counting labels?

Comment: Use `sumif`....

Comment: You could also use a pivot table to create a list of the order number and a sum or count of the quantity.

Comment: If you are using Excel O365, I have a way to do this.  The only approach I have used for this involves dynamic arrays, which is a feature of Excel O365.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output